# PHP mysql pin to top tasks

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table `tbl_task` in my `mysql database`. This table contain

```
db_taskid      db_desc   db_psd      db_pin

    1           test    28-10-2017    0

    2           xxx     27-10-2017    1

    3           yyy     26-10-2017    1
```

the column `db_pin` is use it to put this task at the top of the table that i print to user like what happen in `google keep`. If `db_pin` is 1 that mean this task is put it at the top of the table.

If is 0 that mean this task is not at the top. For that i use this query to select all tasks for the user and order it by 2 columns `db_psd`  this mean planning start date and `db_pin`

**This is the query**

```
select * from tbl_task ORDER BY db_pin desc,db_psd desc
```

This idea work but i have a problem i want the last task pinned be at the top 
in my table i have 2 tasks have 1 in `db_pin`.

Example: I clicked first for taskid number 3 than i click pin to top for taskid number 2 i want the last task click it be at the first like that

```
2   xxxx    27-10-2017

3    yyy    26-10-2017
```

if after i click pin to top for the taskid number 1 than the table will be like that

```
    1           test    28-10-2017    

    2           xxx     27-10-2017    

    3           yyy     26-10-2017
```

Any suggestion to solve this problem ??!!

Comment: Add a column with the time it was pinned and sort on that

Comment: Or save the pin date in the `db_pin` field instead of a simple flag

Comment: You mean in db_pin i add datetime without number 0 and 1 ?!

Comment: Yes, that what I meant - And set a default `NULL` for any non-pinned task

Comment: @AlonEitan i will try that thank you for your reply

Comment: Try this : select * from tbl_task ORDER BY db_pin ,db_psd desc

Comment: Can you additionally show what you want the table/result to look like? I don't understand how the result you have is different from the result you want. But similar to the comments above, if you want to sort by when something was pinned you need to save the timestamp for the pinning action.

Comment: @GratusD. thank you for your reply my problem is solve it by the idea of the other member here i changed db_pin from int to datetime and like that i order by this date and the big datetime will be at the top of my table

Comment: And so this question should be closed. Following advice via the comment (I think) by @AlonEitan :: That a datetime column be used to both indicate something is "pinned" and also allowing wanted sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Use a datetime column (instead of integer) to both indicate something is "pinned" whilst also allowing wanted sorting.